# Getting hardware IDs of mouse that are of the same brand/model

Tags: windows, mouse, device, hid, wmic

I'm developing an inventory and audit system for laboratories. I need to get unique identifiers of peripherals including mouse. As far as I know, device ID will not count as a unique ID since it changes when the mouse is transferred to another PC.

From PC1:

```
USB\VID_15D9&PID_0A4C\6&291D96FC&0&5
```

Transferred to PC2:

```
USB\VID_15D9&PID_0A4C\7&218D78FC&0&1
```

The latter part of the string changes.

I focused on the Hardware ID as a candidate for unique ID which is `USB\VID_15D9&PID_0A4`. I've tried obtaining unique hardware ID of mice using WMIC that are of different brand/model. But when I tried doing it with the same brand of mouse (Genius), I obtained the same hardware ID. Can someone explain to me why that is?

I'm aware that VID is vendor ID and PID is the Product ID (in `HID\VID_0458&PID_003A&REV_0100`). Why can't I obtain a unique identifier of a peripheral? Are there any attributes that may be considered as unique?

Comment: AFAIK, USB devices are not in general required to have unique identifiers, so cheap ones usually don't.

Comment: Why is that if I may ask?

Comment: Presumably because there's no need.  Some types of USB device need to be distinguishable, but why would a computer really need to know whether the mouse you're plugging in is the same one as last time or not?  If it is the same model, then it needs the same device drivers, and for a mouse that's all the computer needs to know.

Comment: I'm keeping an audit of devices in the laboratory. There are possible swapping of devices like mouse in this case. We need to obtain the unique ID of the mouse so that we keep track of swaps. Like if mouse of pc1 is  transferred, our system locates the new location of mouse from pc1 so there's a really great need of unique identifier @HarryJohnston

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to do, though I'm not sure why.  At any rate, it's a very rare use case, and I think it would cost too much to be economically viable.  (I just checked my usual supplier, and it looks like Genius is one of the cheapest brands available.  More expensive brands might include the feature you're looking for; you could check with your supplier.)

Comment: Can we get serial number of the device such as mouse? this will count as unique identifier @HarryJohnston